# How can I use return a string according to object text?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a object a string according to the file type. I'm binding a listview. the listview is files.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "Pictures\\XL_Icon.png";
        }
```

XAML:

```
                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathConverter}}"
                       Height="20"
                       Width="20"
                       Stretch="UniformToFill"
                       />
```

What I would like is

```
if (value.Text == *.xlsx)
{
     return "Pictures\\XL_Icon.png";
}.
```

Comment: `value` is of type `object`, should it be something else that has that `Text` property? You're not very clear about what is passed in the `value` parameter. Does the Text property literally hold `*.xlsx` or do you mean "any filename that ends with the extension xlsx" ?

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking. `object` type has no property called `Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Convert` method parameter, `value', is of type object and there is no`Text` Property for that.

You can try [`EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function of the `string` class

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (value.ToString().EndsWith(xlsx))
    {
     return "Pictures\\XL_Icon.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*.(xlsx)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

regex.Matches(value.Text);